# MYSQL - add new column with default string concat with data from existing column

Tags: mysql

I need to insert a new column of URLs into a table of items based on their ROM code that already exists in a column of my table.

my URL needs to have the following format
/media/marquees/{ROM}.png

```
|  rom  |          marquee_url          |
|---------------------------------------|
| abcd  | /media/marquees/abcd.png      |
| efg   | /media/marquees/efg.png       |
```

I'm fairly confident there are no NULL values in _rom

Comment: you only want to update marquee_url  one time, or want you have a automatic update. Then youn can insert a VIRTUAL COLUMN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generated columns in 5.7.

```
 > CREATE TABLE test_table ( rom varchar(20),   marquee_url  varchar(30) AS (concat("/media/marquees/",rom,".png")) );

 > insert into test_table (rom) values ('abcd'), ('efg');

 > select * from test_table ; 
+------+--------------------------+
| rom  | marquee_url              |
+------+--------------------------+
| abcd | /media/marquees/abcd.png |
| efg  | /media/marquees/efg.png  |
+------+--------------------------+`
```

For more info on how generated columns work, please refer to this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to upgrade to 5.7 and go this route

Answer (score 0):

user `concat` for `marquee_url field` you get result:

`INSERT INTO table_name (room, marquee_url) VALUES (value1, CONCAT( '/media/marquees/',value1))`