# How can i combine the values from 3 varchar columns to one column?

Tags: mysql, sql

For Example

I have the following Columns in a DB-table: Name, Surname, Adress, Contact.
In one row the value for the column name is Smith , the surname Bob and the adress Street1.

How can i combine the mentioned values to the column Contact?
The Value in this row should be like this then:
Bob_Smith_Street1

I want this to be automatically created in the table. so as soon as I right click on the Table -->select 1000 rows, the value is displayed. Without having me to enter the mentioned select command. Is this possible? Can anything be done when creating the table for this. So for example create table employees (Contact(name""surname""address)).

thanks

ps. sorry for my bad english:)

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: hi ysth
When i select 1000 rows the follwong Select version is shown
Select
Name varchar,
surname varchar,
adress varchar,
Contact varchar from employee

Comment: if you execute just the query `select version();` what does it show?

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT()`. For example:

```
select concat(Name, '_', Surname, '_', Adress) as contact from t
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. However, I want this to be automatically created in the table. so as soon as I right click on the Table -->select 1000 rows, the value is displayed. Without having me to enter the mentioned select command.
Is this possible?
Can anything be done when creating the table for this. So for example 
create table employees (Contact(name"_"surname"_"address)).
do you understand what I mean?

Comment: In that's the case, then the answer is already in the closing action: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526409/mysql-add-new-column-with-default-string-concat-with-data-from-existing-column